# R: Replace various values by their group

Tags: r, recode

I want to recode a vector `x` with individuals by their group.

```
set.seed(1)
x<-sample(135,2000,rep=T)
individuals<-1:135
groups<-sample(7,135,rep=T)
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work if there's a expression at the left side of each equal sign, only if there's an explicit vector e.g. `c(7,12,29,31)`.

```
x_recod<-car::recode(x,"individuals[groups=='1']=1;individuals[groups=='2']=2;individuals[groups=='3']=3;individuals[groups=='4']=4;individuals[groups=='5']=5;individuals[groups=='6']=6;individuals[groups=='7']=7")
```

Also I wonder if there's a way to do this without having to mention every group.

Editing: The solution to this example is trivial because those are `x` is a numeric vector, but what if it's characters? E.g.

```
x<-sample(letters,2000,rep=T)
individuals<-letters
groups<-sample(7,26,rep=T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `x` to subset `groups`.

```
newx <- groups[x]
```

Verify the output :

```
head(x)
#[1]  68 129  43  14  51  85
groups[head(x)]
#[1] 6 7 2 3 7 7
head(newx)
#[1] 6 7 2 3 7 7
```

Comment: What if the `x` vector is a character vector? For example, `x<-sample(letters,2000,rep=T); individuals<-letters; groups<-sample(7,26,rep=T)`. I've tried using `groups[which(individuals==x)]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @paulgr In that case, you can use `match`, i.e `groups[match(x, individuals)]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sapply`.

```
x.rec <- x
invisible(sapply(groups, function(g) x.rec[groups == g] <<- g))
head(x.rec)
# [1] 6 2 5 7 6 4
```